# Test string variable for "Blank or Empty" in an apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, string

I have a variable that successfully holds the result from a query in a trigger.  I am able to use this variable to update the Contact record.  However; if the query does not return records the variable is not assigned any value.  I can't seem to test that the variable is blank and assign it a placeholder value.

How can I test the value of ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE when no records are returned and no value is assigned?

Thanks,

Kevin

// Most Recent Contact ExecEd SEM Code
     string ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE;

```
 ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = [select SEM_Code__c from Interaction__c 
 WHERE Contact__c = :record.Contact__c AND SEM_Code__c != null 
 ORDER BY Start_Date_Time__c DESC LIMIT 1].SEM_Code__c;              

 if (String.isBlank(ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE)){
      ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = 'test-blank';
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's you go:

```
List<SEM_Code__c> codes = [
    SELECT SEM_Code__c
    FROM Interaction__c
    WHERE Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
    AND SEM_Code__c != null 
    ORDER BY Start_Date_Time__c DESC
    LIMIT 1
];

String ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE;

//check the emptiness of the list this way before trying to pull the field off

if (codes.isEmpty()) {
    ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = 'placeholdervalue';
else {
    ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = codes[0].SEM_Code__c;
}
```

Comment: Using a ternary might have been a confuser in the answer, but here's a shorthand if you're familiar with it: String ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = codes.isEmpty() ? 'placeholdervalue' : codes[0].SEM_Code__c;

Comment: the type of list and sObject being queried do not match in SOQL...